# How to pass parameters to a view that was previously shown in Flex Mobile Project (I cannot use pushView)

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, textinput, flex-spark

I have a Flex Mobile Project that I am working on.  I am trying to pass parameters from one view to another.  The only problem is that I cannot use navigator.pushView to push the View and the parameter as the view I am pushing to was the previous view.  So this wipes out using the addHandler() and the returnObjectsCreated() as I cannot use pushView.  I am having to use popView because it is my previous view that I have to pass parameters too. Any help would be appreciated.

That class that has the parameters I need to pass is below.  It is a view that shows a list.  So I need to pass list.selectedItem to the popview or previous view...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<amec:BaseBrowseView xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
              xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
              xmlns:amec="com.amec.Components.*"
              title="Select an item">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.amec.BaseSql;

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

        [Bindable]private var resultArr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        protected function myList_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void 
        {

            navigator.popView();


            //Either send a ref to the last view or override createReturn

        }


        [Bindable(event="myDataChanged")]
        private function get myData():ArrayCollection
        {

                           }



    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:List id="list"         
        height="100%" width="100%" 
        dataProvider="{myData}" 
        labelField="DMV_VALUE_1"
        change="myList_changeHandler(event);">
</s:List>


<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
```

Now below is the previous view that I want to popView to that I need to pass parameters to so I can populate the TextInput with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<amec:BaseControl xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
              xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
              xmlns:amec="com.amec.Components.*"
              horizontalCenter="true">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        [Bindable]
        protected var textValue:String;

        protected function control_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            // todo: get control data from view.data


        }

        protected function control_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            parentView.navigator.pushView(TextListView);

        }




    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Label text="Robert says something meaningful goes here" />

<s:TextInput id="ns" text="{textValue}" editable="false" click="control_clickHandler(event)"/>





<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
```

Again I cannot use pushView as the view is already on the stack.

Comment: Store the data in some application-wide scope; such as a static var or in a Dependency Injected value.

Comment: By the way Depency Injection requires a framework which would be a little much work for simply passing a parameter,  there was also eventListeners but they tend to have issues with Garbage Collection based on reference, so I went with a Singleton approach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I looked at using static variables but that was a little messy, I also looked at using Dependency Injection but spending a few hours to set up the framework and get it running is to costly when all I am doing is passing parameters on a popView, so what I came up with is the similar approach I have used when doing Native Android Apps with the Android SDK.  A Singleton with getters and setters.
Basically the way I have been able to do this is with the use of a Singleton sharedInstance.  See code below:

```
package com.controls.Text
{
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;
    [Bindable]

    public class ParameterManager
    {
        private static var instance:ParameterManager = new ParameterManager();
        private var dictionary:Dictionary=new Dictionary(); 


        public function ParameterManager( )
        {
        if (instance != null) { throw new Error('Must use ParameterManager.getInstance().') }
        }

        public static function getInstance(): ParameterManager {
            return instance;
        }

        public function setParameter(key:*, value:*):void
        {
        dictionary[key]=value;  
        }

        public function getParameter(key:*):*
        {
            return dictionary[key];
            }
    }
}
```

The method setting the value of the parameter:

```
        protected function myList_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void 
        {
            var listViewReturnObject:String = new String();
            listViewReturnObject = list.selectedItem.DMV_VALUE_1;
            ParameterManager.getInstance().setParameter("selectedItem", listViewReturnObject);

            navigator.popView();
        }
```

The method getting the value:

```
        protected function control_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {               
            var listViewReturnObject:Object = new Object();

            listViewReturnObject= ParameterManager.getInstance().getParameter("selectedItem");
            if (listViewReturnObject != null)
            {
                dataTxt.text= String(listViewReturnObject);
                ParameterManager.getInstance().setParameter("", null); //Make sure objects are cleared when done.
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to do it the right way, on the previous view (the one you want the result going to, add an eventListener for 'add'.

```
protected function addHandler(event:FlexEvent) : void {
if (navigator.poppedViewReturnedObject != null) {
                var returnedObject : Array = navigator.poppedViewReturnedObject.object as Array;
                if(!returnedObject) return;
                yourData= new ArrayCollection(returnedObject);
            }
```

}

On the view that you are going to pass the object from:

```
override public function createReturnObject():Object {
            var returnedObject : Object = new Object();
            returnedObject = dataYouWantToSendBack;
            return returnedObject;
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, but no dice.  I am going to use the singleton as I can re use this.

Comment: Here I go responding to old posts again.. BUT I have to side with this over the accepted answer.  This worked well for me, and it's a little more tightly scoped as a solution that just accessing some global variable.